# Upgrade SF from 2.8 to 3.x.x

Tags: symfony, migration, symfony-2.8, symfony3.x

I have a problem with the migration from Symfony 2.8 to Symfony 3 and higher. I’ve been trying to update my project for a few days, but I’m blocking the same mistakes. I tried all the solutions I could find on google but no evolutions. Here is my file composer.json

```
{
"name": "My/project",
"license": "proprietary",
"type": "project",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "app/AppKernel.php",
        "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.0.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "3.13",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.1",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "^1.3",
    "sonata-project/core-bundle": "^3.1",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2.1",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "^3.2",
    "sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "^3.1",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^2.5",
    "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "^2.3",
    "google/recaptcha": "^1.1",
    "twig/twig": "1.28.2",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "^1.6",
    "helios-ag/fm-elfinder-bundle": "^6.2",
    "vich/uploader-bundle": "1.5.3",
    "beberlei/doctrineextensions": "^1.0",
    "simplethings/entity-audit-bundle": "^1.0",
    "sentry/sentry-symfony": "^1.0",
    "rollbar/rollbar": "~1.1",
    "mikey179/vfsstream": "^1.6"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^2.3",
    "hautelook/alice-bundle": "^2.0@beta",
    "nelmio/alice": "^3.0@beta",
    "theofidry/alice-data-fixtures": "^1.0@beta",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^4.2",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^6.1",
    "behat/behat": "^3.4",
    "behat/mink": "^1.7",
    "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "^1.3",
    "behat/symfony2-extension": "^2.1",
    "behat/mink-extension": "^2.2",
    "behat/mink-browserkit-driver": "^1.3",
    "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "^1.2",
    "emuse/behat-html-formatter": "^0.1.0",
    "phing/phing": "2.*"
},
"scripts": {
    "symfony-scripts": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@symfony-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@symfony-scripts"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "component-dir": "web/assets"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
    "symfony-var-dir": "var",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    }
}
```

}

I use this command to update : `$ composer update symfony/symfony --with-dependencies --no-scripts`

update is not done because apparently I have conflicts with different versions of my dependencies..yet I can’t update my dependencies in a more recent version

[image]

Need your help please..

Answer (score 0):

You have a conflict because you cannot have `symfony/symfony 3.0.*` and `symfony/cache 3.4` at the same time.

In fact, other bundles that you have locked at a version are not compatible with symfony 3.0, so you need to bump them up as well.

The minimum viable would be to use these dependencies :

```
"symfony/symfony": "3.2.*",
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "^2.0",
"sonata-project/user-bundle": "^4.0",
```

Then just run `composer install` instead of `composer update symfony/symfony`. Composer will do its job, and then you'll have to adapt your code to mitigate all the BC breaks, etc ...

If you cannot change your other dependencies, **then you're stuck with Sf 2.8**.